# how to get data in monthly wise by group the month and union using joins in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here unoinColumn  is return the all the date with out duplicate but i want to get the date group by month 
   
 `month   totalamount`

```
 7/2014    10000

 8/2014    10000
```

`enter code here  var unoinDateColumn = (from agent in db.collections
                 where agent.Date_Time.Value.Year == thisYear
            select agent.Date_Time).Union(from u in db.bank_deposit
            where u.Date_Time.Value.Year == thisYear
             select u.Date_Time).ToList();`

Comment: so you have an amount property in both `collections` and `bank_deposit` ? Or just in `bank_deposit` ?

Comment: no  both i had data in both tables and both tables  have duplicate data

Comment: amont property are in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that, if I understood well.

1. Filter collections and deposits by given year, select date_time and amount
2. Union, group by month, select date in the desired format, and sum amount.

You can of course do all that in one query, but I'm not sure this will be easier to read ;)

```
var collections = db.Collections.Where(x => x.Date_Time.Value.Year == thisYear)
                                .Select(m => new {
                                    dt = m.Date_Time.Value,
                                    amount = m.Amount
                                });

var deposits = db.Collections.Where(x => x.Date_Time.Value.Year == thisYear)
                                .Select(m => new {
                                    dt = m.Date_Time.Value,
                                    amount = m.Amount
                                });

var result = collections.Union(deposits)
                        .GroupBy(m => m.dt.Month)
                        .Select(g => new {
                            date = g.First().dt.ToString("MM/yyyy"),
                            totalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.amount)
                         });
```

Comment: u r query result is like below 07/2014 07/2014,07/2014,05/2014,05/2014

Comment: i want only one 07/2014,05/2014

Comment: @user1983379 did you just cut and paste this code ? If you didn't, could you show your actual code ?